# Is ObjectQuery likely to be supported in future versions of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Is ObjectQuery likely to be supported in future versions of entity framework. I know that is not generally good practice to use SQL with an ORM but have very specialized and narrow use case. I have read some read some things online which tend to indicate that ObjectQuery is quite an old API and am worried it may be discontinued in the near future.

Comment: Any code sample you need to show with us? It's hard to tell what current problem you have without [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made some progress using ObjectQuery and have changed my question.

Comment: It's already been removed from EF Core (a.k.a. EF 7) - so no, it's definitely not something to bet on long term

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that's good to  know